# Changing value after calling variable by using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

so I started programming in C. Now I have a problem with pointers:

```
int * diff(){
  int array[2] = {1,2};
  return array;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int *p;
  p = diff();
  printf("%d\n", *(p));
  printf("%d\n", *(p));

  return 0;
}
```

So after starting the program. My terminal is showing the following:

```
1
0
```

So why is the Value of *p changing ?

Comment: Returning a pointer to local variable == undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

`array` has automatic storage duration (informally, think of this as a "local variable"), and dereferencing the pointer to it that's returned back to `main` is not allowed by the language.

(We call this a *dangling pointer*).

Comment: Sir, nitpick: _"dereferencing the pointer to it that's returned back to main is not allowed by the language"_, well, the language never stops you, all it says that it'll be UB.